Kotlin + Jetpack Compose: vararg with multiple generic types
I have this composable:
@Composable
inline fun <T:Any> AnimatedVisibilityNullable(
    value: T?,
    ...
    crossinline content: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    // for nullable values
    val ref=remember{ Ref<T>() }
    LaunchedEffect(value){
        ref.value = value?:ref.value
    }

    // content
    AnimatedVisibility(
        value!=null && visible(value),
        ...
    ){
        ref.value?.let { value ->
            content(value)
        }
    }
}

When the value its not null, display the content and pass the parameter value null-safe.
I want to know if there's a way to do it more generic? Something like this, but with generic types and vararg:
@Composable
fun <T1:Any,T2:Any> AnimatedVisibilityNullable(
    value1: T1?,
    value2: T2?,
    ...
    content: @Composable (T1,T2) -> Unit
) {
    // for nullable values
    val ref1 = remember { Ref<T1>() }
    val ref2 = remember { Ref<T2>() }

    LaunchedEffect(value1,value2) {
        ref1.value = value1?:ref1.value
        ref2.value = value2?:ref2.value
    }

    // content
    AnimatedVisibility(
        value1!=null && value2!=null,
        ...
    ){
        ref1.value?.let {p1->
            ref2.value?.let { p2 ->
                content(p1,p2)
            }
        }
    }
}

For what i search, its not possible in kotlin, al least there is no syntax for this case. Thanks!

I have no clue what your code does or why you even want to do that, but if you just want your function to work with vararg parameters the best you can get will probably be something like this:
@Composable
fun <T : Any> AnimatedVisibilityNullable(
    vararg values: T?,
    // ...
    content: @Composable (List<T>) -> Unit,
) {
    // for nullable values
    val refs = values.associateWith {
        remember { Ref<T>() }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(*values) {
        refs.forEach { (value, ref) ->
            ref.value = value ?: ref.value
        }
    }

    // content
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = values.all { it != null }
        // ...
    ) {
        val nonNullRefs = refs.values.mapNotNull { it.value }
        if (nonNullRefs.size == refs.size) {
            content(nonNullRefs)
        }
    }
}

Since lambdas cannot have vararg parameters I changed its parameter to a List instead. Also keep in mind that the type inference cannot distinguish each separate type in the varargs parameter (or the List), so it will have the combined supertype of all parameters. That probably won't be a problem since the actual type doesn't seem to be needed anywhere.
As I already said, I do not understand the code, but there are some fishy parts that you might want to take a look at:

Why even use Ref? It doesn't seem to add anything that cannot be achieved by a simple variable.
The LaunchedEffect seems out of place, I don't see why that is needed in the first place since you neither call suspend functions nor need to do any asynchronous work.
In your first example you call visible(value) which your second example does not. If that is still needed you may want to use values.all { it != null && visible(it) } instead.


I'm sorry I haven't explained more. the composable is used to hide or show another composable depending on whether the variables you pass to them are not null, I had also added a second verification with the "visible" callback passing the variables, but in the others I removed them since I did not know how to pass all the variables and each one with its type in the callback.

And from what I see, there is no way to go through different generic types within a vararg, nor to a callback. Although, as you said, it can be done with a single type and in the callback with a list.
